Getting DOMException when trying to use the tileLayer in react leaflet
I'm using react leaflet to display a raster layer from which I need to get the exact raster values on hover. This should be possible in the following way:
  const getColor = (latlng, layer) => {
    console.log(latlng, layer, "1");
    var size = layer.getTileSize();
    var point = layer._map.project(latlng, layer._tileZoom).floor();
    var coords = point.unscaleBy(size).floor();
    var offset = point.subtract(coords.scaleBy(size));
    coords.z = layer._tileZoom;
    var tile = layer._tiles[layer._tileCoordsToKey(coords)];
    console.log("tile", tile);
    if (!tile || !tile.loaded) return null;
    try {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = 1;
      canvas.height = 1;
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.drawImage(tile.el, -offset.x, -offset.y, size.x, size.y);
      return context.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (!mapRef.current) return;
      console.log(layerRef.current);

      mapRef.current.on("mousemove", function (event) {
        const color = getColor(event.latlng, layerRef);
        console.log("color", color);

        return;

      });
    }, 2000);
  });


      return <MapContainer
        ref={mapRef}
        style={{ height: "70vh", width: "80vw", margin: "0 auto" }}
        center={position}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >


        <TileLayer
          ref={layerRef}
          noWrap={true}
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </MapContainer>


So I pass a ref the the <Tile layer/> and use that ref to obtain the exact values using the getColor function.
However when I do this I get the following error:
Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure

Is there any way around this error or another way to obtain exact raster values in react-leaflet on hover of a TileLayer?
